# Scanning SDK for Ipad 2, iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad-2, scanning

I'm trying to embed barcode scanning into my iPad application. I'm considering leveraging an external hardware barcode device that has a native iOS SDK. what's your thoughts? I would prefer to leverage the iPad as oppose to using an external scanning device? Any thoughts on barcode SDK for iPad 3?

Answer (score 2):

No one's going to be able to comment on an 'iPad 3' since there is nothing publicly announced. There's no way we can know at this point what kind of cameras it might have.

If you're scanning 1D barcodes, an external laser-based device may do a much better job. It really depends a lot on the code and the scan conditions.

For 2D codes, QR codes in particular, the cameras on iPhones and iPads work fine, even fixed focus devices. [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) are open source SDKs that can read QR codes on iOS devices. They don't work as well on 1D codes on fixed-focus devices (older iPhones, iPad 2).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Red Laser](http://redlaser.com/sdk/) SDK